# $sceDelegateProvider resource url whitelist has no effect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

https://jsfiddle.net/BRNTZN/05c1agtb/18/

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="myapp.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="mainctrl">
      {{query}}
      <iframe ng-src="https://www.google.be/search?q={{query}}"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    'self',
    'https://www.google.be/**'
  ]);
});

app.controller('mainctrl', function MainController($scope) {
  $scope.query = "javascript";
});
```

When doing the above outside of fiddle I get the following js error in console:

```
Error: [$interpolate:noconcat] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$interpolate/noconcat?p0=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.be%2Fsearch%3Fq%3D%7B%7Bquery%7D%7D
    at angular.js:38
    at Function.Ka.throwNoconcat (angular.js:11887)
    at k (angular.js:12193)
    at ha (angular.js:9606)
    at $b (angular.js:8553)
    at s (angular.js:8378)
    at s (angular.js:8394)
    at s (angular.js:8394)
    at aa (angular.js:8281)
    at angular.js:1782
```

Where the the link leads to the following explanation:

```
Error while interpolating: https://www.google.be/search?q={{query}}
Strict Contextual Escaping disallows interpolations that concatenate multiple expressions when a trusted value is required.  See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce
```

Which is very weird because I am whitelisting "https://www.google.be/**" as evidenced by my fiddle.

Why is the whitelist not having any effect?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ng-src works with $sce. Changing the ng-src to ng-bind-html in the fiddle works.

```
  <iframe ng-bind-html="https://www.google.be/search?q={{query}}"></iframe>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/05c1agtb/19/

Comment: this does indeed make the correct html appear, however the iframe is not rendered at all. I tried using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{{query}} which is actually a better page to test iframes with. The google one does not render in an iframe ever.